# Create counter in tensorflow graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'd like to create a counter in a graph. It would be increased whenever the function runs. Here what i'm trying now. Any ideas?

```
# init variable
tf_i = tf.Variable(1, name='v', dtype=tf.int32, expected_shape=())

# init assign op
tf_i_plus_one = tf.assign_add(tf_i, 1)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# simple test fx
def test(x):
    v = tf.get_variable('v', shape=())
    return x + v

# run test fx
z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(), name='z')
out = test(z)

print(sess.run(out, feed_dict={z: 4}))
sess.run(tf_i_plus_one)

print(sess.run(out, feed_dict={z: 4}))
```

I now get:

```
Attempting to use uninitialized value v_1
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a counter for a function, try the following:

```
def wrap_with_counter(fn, counter):
    def wrapped_fn(*args, **kwargs):
        # control_dependencies forces the assign op to be run even if we don't use the result
        with tf.control_dependencies([tf.assign_add(counter, 1)]):
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped_fn
```

Example usage:

```
dense_counter = tf.get_variable(
    dtype=tf.int32, shape=(), name='dense_counter',
    initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
wrapped_dense = wrap_with_counter(tf.layers.dense, dense_counter)


batch_size = 4
n_features = 8
# dummy input
x = tf.random_normal(
    shape=(batch_size, n_features), dtype=tf.float32, name='x')

out = wrapped_dense(x, 1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    c0 = sess.run(dense_counter)
    print(c0)  # 0
    sess.run(out)
    c1 = sess.run(dense_counter)
    print(c1)  # 1
```

Comment: Thanks. Super helpful. However, for understanding how tf handles variable assignments or updates in the graph, do you have any insights regarding that?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, completely build your graph before you instantiate your session/do variable initialization. The error you got above surprised me - I would have expected something more like `Variable v already exists, disallowed`, but if you separate graph construction from session running things are a lot more predictable. `tf.assign_add` returns a tensor which represents the result of the update, but if that result isn't depended on by anything you call in the session it won't be run, hence the update won't be run. Adding `tf.control_dependencies` is a way to get around that.

Comment: Can I use something like this in a `Dateset` map/filter/apply function in order to get an incremental variable (such as the `global_step`)? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60882387/how-to-get-current-global-step-in-data-pipeline