# How to get current global_step in data pipeline

Tags: tensorflow, tensor2tensor

I am trying to create a filter which depends on the current `global_step` of the training but I am failing to do so properly.

First, I cannot use `tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()` in the code below because it will throw

```
ValueError: Variable global_step already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope? Originally defined at:
```

This is why I tried fetching the scope with `tf.get_default_graph().get_name_scope()` and within that context I was able to "*get*" the global step:

```py
def filter_examples(example):
    scope = tf.get_default_graph().get_name_scope()

    with tf.variable_scope(scope, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        current_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()

    subtokens_by_step = tf.floor(current_step / curriculum_step_update)
    max_subtokens = min_subtokens + curriculum_step_size * tf.cast(subtokens_by_step, dtype=tf.int32)

    return tf.size(example['targets']) <= max_subtokens


dataset = dataset.filter(filter_examples)
```

The problem with this is that it does not seem to work as I expected. From what I am observing, the `current_step` in the code above seems to be 0 all the time (I don't know that, just based on my observations I assume that).

The only thing that seems to make a difference, and it sounds weird, is restarting the training. I think, also based on observations, in that case `current_step` will be the actual current step of the training at this point. But the value itself won't update as the training continues.

If there a way to get the *actual* value of the current step and use it in my filter like above?

---

#### Environment

Tensorflow 1.12.1

Comment: Where is the `global_step` being updated?

Comment: @rvinas This is a good question .. I am using [tensor2tensor](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensor2tensor) (t2t) and only implemented my own `problem`. The code above gets called during the t2t data-pipeline execution and should only return a `tf.data.Dataset`. I was hoping to be able to somehow fetch the `global_step` that is being created by t2t.

Comment: I see. I am not familiar with the t2t framework, but we should make sure `global_step` gets updated somewhere, otherwise, it makes sense that its value stays at 0. Perhaps another option (might not be elegant) would be to maintain your custom `global_step`?

Comment: @rvinas So the `global_step` does get updated but I think I am just not able to get the reference to that particular variable in the graph. As stated, e.g., `get_or_create_global_step()` does throw an exception. As you said, it would be okay to use my own `global_step` or `counter` variable, but I don't really know how I could accomplish something like that. Is there a way to e.g. update a variable whenever a step was made from within this current context?

Comment: Would it be possible to point me where `global_step` gets updated? As an alternative, if you can have your own counter, you could update it as follows: `op = tf.assign_add(counter, 1)` followed by `with tf.control_dependencies(op): # Some operation here before which the counter should be updated`. Using [tf.control_dependencies](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies) allows to include the update of `counter` in a path within the computational graph. Unfortunately, I cannot provide a more specific answer because I do not have reproducible code.

Comment: @rvinas I cloned the [repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensor2tensor) and tried to find the place where they update `global_step` but I couldn't find it. However, your hint to use `tf.control_dependencies()` led me to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensor2tensor/blob/v.1.12.0/tensor2tensor/data_generators/multi_problem.py#L231) which looks like something I could use for my use case.

Comment: @rvinas Your idea with `tf.control_dependencies` is working. It's not the way I wanted it to do at first but it's alright and serves its' purpose. If you want to provide an answer, the bounty is yours. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, having and updating your own counter might be an alternative to using the `global_step` variable. The `counter` variable could be updated as follows:

```
op = tf.assign_add(counter, 1)
with tf.control_dependencies(op): 
    # Some operation here before which the counter should be updated
```

Using [tf.control_dependencies](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies) allows to "attach" the update of `counter` to a path within the computational graph. You can then use the `counter` variable wherever you need it.

Answer (score -1):

If you use variables inside datasets you need to reinitilize iterators in `tf 1.x`.

```py
iterator = tf.compat.v1.make_initializable_iterator(dataset)
init = iterator.initializer
tensors = iterator.get_next()

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        sess.run(init)
        for example in range(num_examples):
            tensor_vals = sess.run(tensors)
```

Comment: Note you may be better off sorting your initial dataset, pre-calculating length cutoffs and then using `Dataset.take`

Comment: Sorry, this is not an option that will work with the tensor2tensor framework.